# How to reference classes from a Windows Form Application in an ASP.net Web Site project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Basically, I need to use classes and methods from Project A, which is a Windows Form Application in Project B, which is an ASP.net website project (using C# in Visual Studio 2010). I can't simply add a reference, as that requires conversion of the Form Application to a Class Library. I also don't want to merge the classes and methods I need from Project A into Project B.

Is this possible?

Comment: Clean your code : classes which are used in both projects must be put in a third "class library" project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need is a class library where you can put the classes which are used in both web app and windows app. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3cye135%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on how to create a class library. **Remember - the class library should not contain any web or windows specific code**. Please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) up for the best practices.

Answer (score 3):

Put your widows form class and its method in class library(making new project). 
And make it as reference in your web project